# About malloc() and globals variables

Tags: c

I'm wondering what this code sample means. And how can I be sure my structure called "my_struct" can be safely allocated in memory ?

Thanks for your help.

```
MyStructType_t my_struct;

int main(void)
{
    MyStructType_t *p;
    p = malloc (sizeof(MyStructType_t ));
    my_struct= *p;

    [...]
}
```

I try this code (because compiler doesn't warn me) and even if it makes no sense it seems to solve my issue which is I have some fields of my_struct that are erased with no reason as I try to explain.

```
int main(void)
{
    // my main struct have many fields which are initialized
    my_struct.flag1 = 1;
    my_struct.flag2 = 2;
    memset(my_struct.buffer, 0, 10);
   [..]
}

void timer_callback( void )
{
    // Here i try to parse my buffer to get data from UART
    if(my_struct.buffer[0] == 2)
    {
       // we are ok
       // Then I exectute random code to write in eeprom values from the  buffer
       EEPROM_write(buffer[1]); ...

       // If I check the value of flag1, the value has changed to 0.
       [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense.

Comment: What is the data type of `MyStructType_t`? Just using struct in variable name won't make it structure.

Comment: `my_struct` has *static* storage duration, it exists for the whole running time of the program, so there's nothing to allocate. The code just copies the (indeterminate!) contents of a dynamically allocated object to this static instance. It indeed makes no sense at all and I have just one question: why?

Comment: What this line `my_struct= *p;` is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know I'm just asking this because compiler doesn't warn me. I just look for a solution to my issue which is that my_struct has fields that are erased when executing random code.

Comment: Post a [mcve] if you're trying to solve a problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what 'erased when executing code' means but it might be a buffer over-run bug. C typically doesn't range check so errors in pointer arithmetic (or array index) can result in code overwriting (apparently) unrelated areas of memory. If that's your problem this is no way to fix it.

Comment: You have not presented a complete translation unit, but I see nothing in what you did present to suggest that the program violates any language constraint.  If it indeed doesn't then all conforming compilers should compile it successfully, and they are not obligated to issue any diagnostics.  Better compilers do try to diagnose issues beyond those that they are *required* to spot, but you should not rely on them to warn you about semantic problems.

Comment: The added snippet doesn't really clarify the question (the *opposite* for me, what are you doing there?) But it **does** give a hint that this is indeed about embedded programming. Therefore, you should probably *avoid* `malloc()` altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line declares the variable `my_struct` in the static storage.

The first two lines of `main` declare a pointer and allocates memory for it in the dynamic storage.

The third line **copies** the content of the memory allocated in the first two line of `main` (in dynamic storage) to the memory allocated in the first line (in static storage).

The content itself is unknown and is garbage, so this code is meaningless. It will work, but nothing meaningful will be in `my_struct` when it's done.

Comment: well, to be precise, there are no "memory spaces" or a "heap" in terms of C. Better use the C terms (*static storage duration* vs *dynamic storage duration*) or explain that you're writing about typical *implementations* of C. Apart from that, probably as good as an answer can be given that strange question ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you for the suggestion, and thanks for the compliment:)